# Java - Pass multiple parameters to ajax post

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I have this simple controller from ajax request. It works but I wanted to return many stuff, not only List TestFlow.getFlow(flowName);

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/execute-flow/getFlow" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<String> getFlow(@RequestParam("flowName") String flowName) {
    return TestFlow.getFlow(flowName);
}
```

Can I return multiple things to the ajax post?

For example:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/execute-flow/getFlow" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<String> getFlow(@RequestParam("flowName") String flowName) {
    return TestFlow.getFlow(flowName);
    return TestFlow.getInputs(flowName);
    return TestFlow.getCode(flowName);
}
```

Comment: No, but you can create a structure holding all three values

Comment: you need to make a custom `Object` for this. Maybe also have a look at a basic java tutorial. Multiple `return` statements are in no language allowed

Comment: can't I make a json array?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're after, but

```
return Arrays.asList(
        TestFlow.getFlow(flowName),
        TestFlow.getInputs(flowName),
        TestFlow.getCode(flowName));
```

should work, provided that all of these are of the same type (String).